# msbuild timeout

Tags: msbuild

Well I have a fairly large project which msbuild keeps timing out on.

How can we stop msbuild from timing out?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

If you **want** to get a timeout, you could use cruiscontrol.net or Nant or some other build platform, and you can specify a timeout there.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this [hotfix from MS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB948677).

Per the Hotfix information: If a build takes longer than 59 minutes then it will timeout.

Comment: Well I have a fairly large project which msbuild keeps timing out on. I'm sure there is going to be a way to get around this,right?

Comment: You question makes it appear that you are looking for a way to **have** msbuild timeout instead of a way to prevent it from timing out.

Comment: @unknown: you might want to close this question and try again. Your question is asking for a way to turn on timeouts, but your comment suggests you don't want it to timeout.  How about posting the relevant portion of your build log.